# Failed to load CSS file in elementore inside wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Hello Stackowerflow comunity.

I am suffering from the issue which is "Failed To Load Resource" inside wordpress.

When I close the elementore, all the contents of my website goes break and when i reopen it the website looks great.

In this period what happen is, inside my wordpress directory wp-plugings/upload/elementore/css it contain all css files of elemetore all css files removed auotomaticaly and
when i reopen the elementore all file comes up

What to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your site is breaking down when you deactivate the Elementor plugin. It is common for plugins to remove codes/files generated by them when they're deactivated.

If you need to deactivate the Elementor plugin, yet keep the styling:

What you can do is:

copy all the codes from the css files in wp-content/uploads/elementor/css and paste them in one of the css files in your child theme, or in the theme settings or customizer. (Make sure that all the css code has proper selectors instead of pseudo selectors).